# Bundle not working with rbenv and cannot gem install bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I was running into an issue with bundler when using rbenv.  I had switched from ruby 2.3.1 to 2.5.1 a while ago, but I noticed the following error when trying to run bundler inside of a shell script in an ansible task.

```
rbenv: bundle: command not found

```
The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.2.2
  2.3.1
```

```

I saw some solutions to this where you had to install bundler when on a specific ruby version.  However even uninstalling bundler and reinstalling it did not resolve the issue. It seemed due to some gem issue that I could not install bundler on specific ruby versions, thus reinstalling bundler did nothing for me.

Comment: It is always safe to remove rbenv and all installed rubies, then reinstall from scratch. Strange issues like this are typically resolved by a clean installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However I did find a very manual solution to this.

I noticed how `rbenv whence bundle` specified that bundle was active in some ruby versions, but not others. I tracked down [the portion of rbenv whence command to find out where it was looking](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/libexec/rbenv-whence#L24) and saw that it looked under the following path for each ruby version installed under rbenv: `~/.rbenv/versions/$VERSION/bin/`

If you look under the path for the gem without bundler (for me this was ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/) you will notice that it is not there. However under other versions that whence can recognise you will see the executable is there (for me it was there under `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle` and `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle`).

So I copied the executable over from the working ruby version to the one that was broken. Then at the top of the file you will notice sha-bang is set to the other ruby version (for me this was `#!/Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby`). Change the version path to the ruby version you want to fix and then it will all magically start working.

Comment: I will advise others to not do this and just run gem install bundle or find a different solution

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you run your ansible scripts in an environment without rbenv. In other words, it is preferable to be using vagrant or a VM to practice your scripts in.

If your project really needs rbenv, please use the ansible rbenv library to work with it, but running it on your host machine is a dangerous way to develop because it is not easily reversible.

Hope this helps!